# Rotating a sprite around its center

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to figure out how to use the origin in Draw method to rotate a sprite around its center. I was hoping somebody could explain the correct usage of origin parameter in Draw method.

If I use the following Draw method (without any rotation and origin specified) the the object is drawn at the correct/expected place:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, destinationRectangle, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

However, if I use the origin and rotation like shown below, the object is rotating around is center but the object is floating above the expecting place (by around 20 pixels.)

```
Vector2 origin = new Vector2(myTexture.Width / 2 , myTexture.Height / 2 );
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, destinationRectangle, null, Color.White, ballRotation, origin, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

Even if I set the ballRotation to 0 the object is still drawn above the expected place

```
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, destinationRectangle, null, Color.White, 0.0f, origin, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

Is seems that just by setting the origin, the placement of the object changes.

Can somebody tell me how to use the origin parameter correctly.

---

## Solution:

Davor's response made the usage of origin clear. 
The following change was required in the code to make it work:

```
Vector2 origin = new Vector2(myTexture.Width / 2 , myTexture.Height / 2 );
destinationRectangle.X += destinationRectangle.Width/2;
destinationRectangle.Y += destinationRectangle.Height / 2;
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, destinationRectangle, null, Color.White, ballRotation, origin, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this is correct use of origin. but now your position changed also to center, it's not on top left corner anymore, its on center. and it's floating for `width/2` and `height/2` from position befor seting origin.

[image]

so if your texture is 20x20, you need to subtract X by 10 (width/2) and Y by 10 (height/2) and you will have original position.

Comment: This makes sense. So it seems that the position we are specifying in draw method is for the origin and not for the starting position of object.

Comment: Don't you mean Y by 10 (height/2)?